# Found an URL of .jsp website with GET parameter probably where input is encoded like base64

Tags: jsp, web, url, base64, decode

Can anyone please explain this.

Found an URL in a .jsp website: https://###.###.##/eu/res/viewExamStudentResults.htm?=nSwa6GoRC%2Bsy5uqnd2iSPcdlMOS8WR%2Fz%2FfbusQGa4tU%3D

URL Decoded with [**www.urldecoder.io**](https://www.urldecoder.io/) : https://###.###.##/eu/res/viewExamStudentResults.htm?=nSwa6GoRC+sy5uqnd2iSPcdlMOS8WR/z/fbusQGa4tU=

Here seems like a GET request with parameter as `nSwa6GoRC+sy5uqnd2iSPcdlMOS8WR/z/fbusQGa4tU=`

It's like base64 encoded. But unable to decode it properly.
Can anyone help on this.

Comment: what do you mean with "unable to decode it properly"? I see only characters that belong to the base64 character set and it's also properly padded, so it should be no problem for any base64 decoder to decode it. Another question is what is actually encoded here. Ususally you use base64 encoding to encode binary data to transport the on text based protocols. So the result is a basically a byte array, which could be the some sort of encryped or hashed data.

Comment: Really I just think that's a unique identifier for each user. I can't quite understand why you would ever need to decode that. @jps Also, I seem to be able to reproduce his error, so I don't think it's that simple.

Comment: @Aniox which error can you reproduce? I don't see any error mentioned in the question.

Comment: @jps Nevermind - that was stupid. It is base64 - it's just that when you decode it it's not legible.

Comment: @Aniox that's the common problem, people decode a base64 string, find nothing readable in it and think decoding failed. No, it decodes just fine, it's just the content that is not what was expected.

Comment: @jps Rookie mistake! I guess I learned something new today!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@jps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7329832/jps) so aptly said:

> It's like base64 encoded. But unable to decode it properly. Can anyone help on this.

It does decode properly. This is what `nSwa6GoRC+sy5uqnd2iSPcdlMOS8WR/z/fbusQGa4tU=` decodes to in base64:

```
,èjë2æê§wh’=Çe0ä¼Yóýöî±šâÕ
```

Just because it isn't legible doesn't mean it isn't base64 encoded.

Furthermore, it's probably a completely random or hashed key that is used to identify a particular document.